# FM receiver with 2N3904

Tags: transistors, oscillator, frequency-modulation

[image: schematic]

Please explain how these 2 transistors work.
I don't understand how it active an amplify the signal.

Source: https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/simple-diy-fm-receiver-circuit-on-internet

Comment: Welcome! Where does the schematic come from? Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: If it works it is probably a superegenerative receiver where the transistors form an oscillator and tuned slightly off frequency where ‘slope detection’ is used to recover the audio. Note that these designs also radiate like a transmitter and can cause interference.

Comment: i read it on this site https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/simple-diy-fm-receiver-circuit-on-internet
i dont know how to simulate the FM input too.

Comment: the information about the origin of the diagram belongs in the question ... it does not belong in a comment ... please edit your question

Comment: @Kartman - this forms an injection locked oscillator. BY using slope demodulation the audio content can be recovered.

Answer (score 4):

The [source website](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/simple-diy-fm-receiver-circuit-on-internet) asks, "*Do they really work?*"
And their conclusion was:

> ...it's absolutely not worth it to waste time on building and testing
> this kind of simple FM radio receiver circuit because it's not made to
> be used for day to day application.

This is an oscillator using two back-to-back transistors that strongly trades oscillating energy back-and-forth between each other. It responds to antenna signals close to its natural oscillating frequency set by the parallel LC resonator.

Out of curiosity, ran a LTspice simulation. When two 2N3904 transistors were simulated, their exact similarity made the oscillator difficult to start because of circuit symmetry.
When a similar transistor (2N4124) having slightly different internal model was substituted for one, it oscillated with no fuss. LC resonator was set for oscillation near 100MHz, and a 100MHz signal source modulated with a 5 kHz sine wave with 75kHz deviation was applied:
[image: circuit diagram back-to-back oscillator]

5 kHz audio at the 22k resistor (at the marker) was -65.8 dBV, while oscillation amplitude at 100 MHz was -42 dBV:
[image: FFT plotting audio and RF oscillator signal]

This is a plain regenerative receiver, and doesn't seem to be a super-regen. It seems that some asymmetry enhances its operation. Attaching an antenna to one arm should provide some asymmetry. Too much asymmetry can kill oscillations. Someone passing by the antenna can de-tune the oscilator as well.

As C2 is tuned through this strong 100 MHz signal source, audio amplitude goes through a maximum when the signal sources captures the oscillator's frequency:

- C2=6pf: Audio=-89.1dBV, oscillator frequency=108.3 MHz
- C2=7pf: Audio=-87.5dBV, oscillator captured @ 100 MHz
- C2=8pf: Audio=-66.5dBV, oscillator captured @ 100 MHz
- C2=9pf: Audio=-65.8dBV, oscillator captured @ 100 MHz
- C2=10pf: Audio=-54.1dBV, oscillator captured @ 100 MHz
- C2=11pf: Audio=-75.5dBV, oscillator frequency=95.957 MHz
- C2=12pf: Audio=-94.1dBV, oscillator frequency=93.989 MHz

Is this worthwhile? It is likely that a weak station next to a strong one will be masked because the strong station will capture the oscillator....**adjacent channel interference** will be rather bad.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, what is supposed to happen is this:

T1 and T2, together with R1, C1 and L1, form an oscillator. If there is a signal present on the antenna, which is near the resonant frequency of the oscillator, it will "pull" the oscillator to resonate at that frequency. The voltage across the LC tank is highest when the oscillator resonates at the natural frequency LC tank, and falls off as the oscillator resonates further away from the natural frequency. Since an FM signal at the antenna changes frequency, it will cause the oscillator to change frequency, and consequently the voltage across the tank to change.

The LM386 is an *audio* amplifier, so it pretty much ignores the high frequency component of the oscillator output.

Either distortion in the LM386 or in the oscillator circuit (I don't know which for sure, but I suspect T1 and T2) creates an audio frequency component, which is then amplified by the LM386.

In practice, there are a number of problems with this circuit.

**Parasitic capacitance in transistors**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdyQMQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit above does oscillate, as one hopes. If we calculate the natural resonant frequency of the tank circuit we get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{22*10^{-12}*1*10^{-6}}} = 33.9312 MHz$$

However, when we look at the simulated oscillogram

[image]

we see that the frequency of oscillation is a little on the low side -- under 30 MHz.

If we change capacitor C1 to 2.2pF, \$1/2\pi\sqrt{LC}\$ gives us 107.302 MHz (near the high end of the commercial FM broadcast band in the US).

However, the actual oscillation frequency is only about 40 MHz :-(

[image]

In fact, if we remove C1 completely, the oscillator continues to oscillate but only at about 45 MHz.

[image]

What is happening is the parasitic capacitances within Q1 and Q2 are being added to the capacitance of C1. Reversing the resonant frequency calculation, we calculate the parasitic capacitances (using 2N3904 transistors) to be about 12.5 pF!

So, to get into the commercial FM broadcast band, we will need to reduce the inductance of L1. Unfortunately, in my simulations, the circuit fails to oscillate if L1 is much below 1 uH. Playing around with components, such as changing the value of R1, or tweaking transistor parameters might get the circuit to oscillate, but I didn't bother trying to find the Goldilocks values because a rather more serious problem came to light.

**Loading of the Tank Circuit by the Antenna**

So far, we have simply looked at an oscillator circuit. However, there has been no antenna attached. The purpose of the antenna is to provide a signal which the oscillator will lock onto. However, an antenna also acts like a load. Power not only comes into the antenna from distant transmitters. Power from the oscillator will also flow into the antenna and be radiated out into space. Numerous experiments, using different reasonable values of antenna impedance, and coupling strategies, show that with the antenna connected, in the absence of any kind of impedance transformation circuit between the antenna and oscillator, the oscillator will simply fail to oscillate.

This could be fixed by adding a passive network consisting of capacitor(s) and inductors(s). It could also be fixed by adding a common base (low input impedance, high output impedance) BJT amplifier to the circuit. But neither of these are found in the circuit circulating on the internet.

After describing how to operate this FM radio, as if it has been build, tested, and works, [electronicshub.org](https://www.electronicshub.org/fm-radio-circuit/) provides this disclaimer buried toward the end of the page:

> **Limitations of the Circuit:**
> This is a theoretical circuit and it requires some changes to implement it practically.

I think it most definitely requires changes to work.

Comment: The bias in the oscillator will vary with the amplitude of oscillation. Since the oscillation amplitude varies with frequency the result is FM demodulation providing the oscillator is tuned to slightly lower or higher than the signal frequency; this is known as slope demodulation.